# Looking for an equation for figuring duplicate numbers

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure the number of duplicate numbers I would see from using only the first 6 digits of 16 digit decimal serial numbers.   Suppose I'm building widgets and assigning 16 digit serial numbers and later I find that sorting through these numbers is no fun and I decide to use only the first 6 digits of the 16 digit serial number.  How many duplicate numbers would I encounter?  Can someone generate an equation for this?

Comment: To make sure the intention is clear: There's 1000 numbers with three decimal digits. But if I drop the last digit, there's only 100 possibilities. Is that the kind of thing you want?

Comment: Assuming we are speaking about decimal numbers, then is $10^{10}$ number, you are looking for?

Comment: Tricky question.  Suppose the following (questionable) assumptions are made: [1] For each assigned 16 digit number, each of its 16 digits are assigned randomly from the set $\{0,1,\cdots, 9\}$.  [2] No 16 digit number is ever re-used. [3] There have been exactly $n$ serial numbers assigned.  If $n$ happens to equal $10^{(16)}$, then, as the comment of @zkutch indicates, the number of duplicates is $10^{(10)}.$  Therefore, I would speculate that the number of expected duplicates is $$10^{(10)} \times \frac{n}{10^{(16)}}.$$

Comment: I should emphasize : this isn't really my field, so I could easily be mistaken.  However, it is reasonable to surmise that as $n$ decreases, the expected number of duplicates should also decrease.

Comment: I should also point out that I may have abused the word *duplicate*.  Perhaps, what I should have said was that given any random 6 digit (zero filled) number, such as $012345$, I was estimating the exact number of serial numbers that begin $012345$.  Note, that this may make the problem more complex, because as stated, the number of serial numbers that begin $012345$ could equal $0$.  If you select a widget, and examine its serial number, you are really asking how many times you expect its first 6 digits to occur in any of the *other* $(n-1)$ numbers.

Comment: Here, you then have the minor complication that if (for example) the widget has the number $0123450123450123$, then there are only $\left[10^{(10)}\right] - 1$ possible serial numbers that any of the other $(n - 1)$ widgets might have that happen to begin $012345$.